# Composer issues while upgrading Magento 2.0rc to 2.0

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, ssh

I have installed Magento 2.0 rc in AWS and tried to update my `composer.json` to update it to Magento 2.0.

Ran the command `sudo composer config composer.json` but received an red box with the error

> [RuntimeException]  `composer.json` is not defined.

I've also tried to run the following command with no response from bash.
`composer config repositories.magento composer http://repo.magento.com`

Your help is much appreciated.
George Ng

Answer (score 0):

`composer config` is used to manage composer settings. There is also usually no need to run it with `sudo`. To update project, run `cd <magento_root_dir> && composer update`.

Note, that Magento 2.0 has backward incompatible changes and it may be better to install it from scratch.